# What to do with this sort of dupes?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to the Meta side of Ask Ubuntu, so hopefully this isn't itself a dupe.

There are at least 3 questions which deal with adding proxy exceptions in Ubuntu. I think it'd be good to tidy them into one.

[Setting up proxy to ignore all local addresses](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11274/setting-up-proxy-to-ignore-all-local-addresses)

[Where to set proxy ignore list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68089/where-to-set-proxy-ignore-list)

[Proxy exceptions in 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135089/proxy-exceptions-in-12-04-lts?lq=1)

The first doesn't mention the version of Ubuntu, but does not include the no_proxy env variable

The second specifies 11.04 and the answer uses dconf-editor

The third specifies 12.04 and the best answer mentions dconf-editor and gconf-editor, but doesn't mention no_proxy

Personally, I'd add no_proxy to the last and mark the other two as dupes, but with only 108 points, I assume that's beyond me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly [Setting up proxy to ignore all local addresses](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11274/setting-up-proxy-to-ignore-all-local-addresses) is best quality wise, but the main answer uses Gconf which has been replaced by Dconf (except perhaps in 12.04...)

[Where to set proxy list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68089/where-to-set-proxy-ignore-list) is more up to date as it uses Dconf instead of Gconf *(though I think some Desktops do have a thing to convert gconf settings to dconf)*

[Proxy Exceptions in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135089/proxy-exceptions-in-12-04-lts?lq=1) is old as well, and I think should be flagged as a dupe of the *first* due to age

Anyway, they are still all relatively ancient (I think the option has been in Network Settings since 13.10~), so I think if someone (I can *later...*) posts a updated answer (probably on the first), including which versions it is compatible with - e.g:

> ## For 14.04

and edit the old questions to say for example

> ## For 12.04 and older

By the way, another thing you can do is to comment below the questions linking to the possible dupes - e.g:

[image]

This should direct users searching the web, and other users can flag as a dupe if they think necessary. Questions can also be merged when they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

The question "Setting up proxy to ignore all local addresses" has the best answers by far, but was asked in nov 2010 and this age of distribution is unsupported, I would leave this alone.

The 12.04 question has an answer indicating that a solution in the 11.10 answer fixed the issue for them on 12.04 and another saying `me too`, these should be comments not answers so this question has some junk answers.

Based on this evidence I would, ignore the first due too its age and flag the third question as a dupe of the second as the second question has better all round content.

Perhaps leave a comment indicating the 11.10 solution is working on 12.04 ( and maybe up)